# How to get the weather conditions based on the user’s current GPS location

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, location, weather-api

Everything works with my code except the fact that the current location displays somewhere else. I live in Kuils River and it gives me the weather conditions for Edgemead. How do I get it for the current location where I am at? Can anyone help me with this one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lat, lon, api_url;

  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    $('#showTemp').on('click', function() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(gotLocation);

      function gotLocation(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;

        api_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&units=metric&appid=b231606340553d9174136f7f083904b3';
        APPID: '53f9d8e4213222cf517d86dc406d67fc'

        $.ajax({
          url: api_url,
          method: 'GET',
          success: function(data) {
            var tempr = data.main.temp;
            var location = data.name;
            var desc = data.weather.description;
            $('#result').text(tempr + '°' + location);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('Your browser doesnt support geolocation. Sorry.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't that code doing that?

Comment: This has nothink to do with your code, because it's correct. GeoLocation can be imprecise

Comment: The code is giving me the weather and the location but the area is wrong I live in Kuils River it gives me a location name Edgemead

Comment: `I live in Kuils River and it gives me the weather conditions for Edgemead` that's simply down to either inaccuracy in the API or the geolocation. The code itself is fine. The only solutions you have are to use a device with a better GPS module, or find an API which has a higher granularity on its area reporting

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an error at:

```
api_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' +
          lat + '&lon=' + 
          lon + '&units=metric&appid=b231606340553d9174136f7f083904b3';
          APPID: '53f9d8e4213222cf517d86dc406d67fc'
```

//

The appid is there twice. Can you give me the coordinates (lat, lon) you're expecting? You should be able to plug in the url directly in your browser to see what you're getting. Have you tried that?

Comment: Here is the task they gave me. Write a single page application that will show the weather conditions based on the user’s current GPS location. You are welcome to use the framework of your choice (Angular, Ember, React etc.).Use Git for version control—and send us a link to your repository when submitting your test.

Comment: The framework doesn't matter in this case. It's just an api call. Did you fix the appid and try it again?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I notice it's not being served over ssl/https, and that's causing problems for me in jsfiddle.

Comment: No im not getting any errors temperature is correct its just the location but i guess if i dont come right with the location ill leave it as is because there is nothing wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

The location is based on where your Internet connection "Break Out", this code seems to use the browser/HTML5 `getCurrentPosition()` API.

Replace this with the actual GPS values and it will be more accurate.